# HTML character codes in alt tag

Tags: html, accessibility, alt

I am writing an alt attribute for an image and it includes an ampersand. Should I put the HTML character code, `&amp;` in the alt attribute or can I just put an ampersand? Would the same be true for the title attribute?

```
<img alt="This & that"/>
```

versus

```
<img alt="This &amp; that"/>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attributes and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#alt

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I don't think there is any need for code, if you look at Matt's links, you are fine adding in the ampersand. (Though I recommend simply switching it to and)

Comment: @naivists, OP's question is related to an image tag, not a title tag.

Comment: You should use either `&amp;` or the word and like IllinoisTim mentioned. Doing `alt="logo for Tom & Jerry"` will be a validator warning since "`& `" is not a valid entity.